# Concate values of a certain column in a different column depending on id in SQL

Tags: sql

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 1 | Mary |
| 2 | Patricia |
| 2 | Charlie |
| 3 | Jane |
| 3 | Karen |
| 3 | MJ |
| 3 | Roland |

The output should look like this

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John,Mary |
| 2 | Patricia, Charlie |
| 3 | Jane, Karen, MJ,Roland |

Comment: What is your DBMS product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/) and [SQLite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/), you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregation function:

```
SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(col1) AS values_
FROM tab
GROUP BY id
```

In [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-aggregate.html) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), you can use the `STRING_AGG` aggregation function:

```
SELECT id,
       STRING_AGG(col1, ',') AS values_
FROM tab
GROUP BY id
```

In [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm) and [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-listagg), you can use the `LISTAGG` aggregation function:

```
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(col1, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY col1) AS values_
FROM tab
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the DB you use. Lemon showed already good ways for the different DB's.
I just want to add another one since `STRING_AGG` was introduced in SQL Server 2017. If you use an older SQL Server DB, you can use `STUFF` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id,
STUFF(
     (SELECT ',' + col1
      FROM yourtable t2
      WHERE t1.id = t2.id
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      ,1,1,'')  AS "values"
FROM yourtable t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 11gR2 and later...

```sql
Select
    ID, 
    ListAgg(COL1, ', ') OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) "VALUES" 
From tbl
Group by ID
Order by ID
```